# The Meaning of "Simply a child of her times"

Tags: meaning

This is the sentence that this phrase appears in.

Finally, there are writers for whom Ban Zhao is neither heroine nor villain, but simply a child of her times.

I thought this meant Ban Zhao was gullible and didn't understand the world around her. Hence, she is labeled as a "child"

Could someone please tell me what this phrase actually means?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ban Zhao is sometimes called a Confucian feminist, but she was famous for a treatise she wrote called "Lessons for Women", which pretty much taught that women should be obedient  to their husbands.

> child of her times

...means that her thoughts and views were created during her formative period as a child by the circumstances and daily reality that surrounded her, as well as by the philosophy that supported paternalism and permeated Chinese thinking of the time.